# Xamarin Forms c# - java exited with code 1 in VS Studio for Windows

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to compile an android app with XF.  I am getting the infamous java.exe exited with code 1 error message.  I have enabled proguard.

I have gotten the error just from enabling proguard.

The error only seems to happen in VS for Windows.  I got a different error in VSMac, but don't have that right here in front of me.

Updating proguard from it's home on sourceforge doesn't seem to do anything for me.

I have put a new proguard.cfg file in my project and have set the build property to be a proguard configuration file.

I don't know what to do here.  I'm looking for any suggestions.

TIA.

Update 1:
I didn't add the build output because I couldn't find a good exception in it.  I just have the following that I can find in the build output. 
I wish I could find the error easily.  I had turned on the build output.   the only exception i can find is listed below. I checked the targets file and the line reference is for the Proguard section.

```
1>      at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:485)
1>      at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:271)
1>      at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:113)
1>      at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:572)
1>  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2550,3):
```

Link to build output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jl1o2hf7aeji243/BuildOutput.zip?dl=0

Comment: Get the full error by enabling msbuild diagnostic logging and add it to your question... also if the proguard file has a U+FEFF byte order mark (BOM)) it will fail...

Comment: you need to add few exceptions in your custom progaurd eg suppose you are using google play library so u need to put  exception rule for progaurd

Comment: fyi, I have also tried this on my mac and gotten the same error.  Yesterday, there was a different error.